# Keep getting Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome

I get this error in google chrome console when trying to disable a button if text boxes are empty:

```
function isEmpty() {
  var r = document.getElementById;
  if (r("box1").value.length >= 1 && r("box2").value.length >= 1 && r("box3").value.length >= 1 && r("box4").value.length >= 2 && r("box5").value.length >= 2 && r("box6").value.length >= 3 && r("box7").value.length >= 1)
    r('#add').disabled = false
  else
    r('#add').disabled = true
  setTimeout(isEmpty, 250)
}
isEmpty();
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getElementById` requires a calling context of `document`. Use `.bind` to bind `r` to `document`:

```
var r = document.getElementById.bind(document);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can replace `r = document.getElementById` with `r = x => document.getElementById(x)`.